# Hot key for switching back to Sources from console

Tags: google-chrome, hotkeys, developer-tools

Anyone knows how to put focus back to sources editor in google chrome developer tools?

For example, I'm inside sources editor do some debugging stuff then I want to evaluate some expressions in console and I'm going to open console using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> hotkey. After inspection of variables I want return back to sources editor but how? For sure I can use mouse but it will be great to find a special hotkey.

Comment: with `Esc` hotkey you can return from console to main window (Elements, source, nework, etc) in chrome developerTools.

Comment: @Morteza Asadi yes...but I don't get focus back, does it work for you?

Comment: just return to main window, not focus...